# Node packages not installable

Tags: node.js

I'm running this code and sometimes I get it to work other times it fails.

Its build by node (not by me ofcourse)

When I run it I often get package not found so I install it and then I get this error?

It's like it's not letting me install the node packages.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-schedule'
Require stack:
- /home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/bots/hashtagcount1.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/bots/hashtagcount1.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/bots/hashtagcount1.js' ]
}
pi@raspberrypi:~/Tools-for-Instagram $ npm install node-schedule

> canvas@2.6.1 install /home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v72-linux-glibc-arm.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for canvas@2.6.1 and node@12.16.3 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pixman-1' found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.97-v7+
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.97-v7+
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/pi/Tools-for-Instagram/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@1.5.2 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@1.5.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-data@1.5.2 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@1.5.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-layers@1.5.2 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@1.5.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2020-06-28T15_05_27_886Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The node-canvas-prebuilt has been deprecated going by the notes on GitHub.

Try:

```
npm install --save canvas
```

then try the schedule import.

Thing that has me baffled is that node-schedule does not list this as a dependency based on [its package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) docs!?!

Answer (score 0):

What you see is that it fails to find a prebuilt package matching your required versions and falls back to trying to compile it. I guess sometimes it can work on other setups because it will need other versions depending on what you have installed.
Here, somehow, the compilation fails.

I also struggled with the 'canvas' module not wanting to be installed/compiled and found out from the module's [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas/v/2.6.1) that you would need the following dependencies in order to build it:

```
libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev
```

So if you are on a Raspberry Pi, assuming you are running Raspbian aka Raspberry Pi OS, you can install the needed packages for compilation like this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev
```

Hopefully now when you try to install that module, after failing to find the correct version, it will successfully compile it.